# Is there any way to get the comment string for an extension, as set in the extension control file?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I'm writing a foreign data wrapper program as a PostgreSQL extension.
Is there any way to get the comment string set in the extension control file from my C program?
The comment was created by PostgreSQL when I ran `CREATE EXTENSION myFDW`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comment for an extension by querying the [`pg_description`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-description.html) and the [`pg_extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-extension.html) system catalogs:

```
SELECT d.description
FROM pg_description AS d
   JOIN pg_extension AS e ON d.objoid = e.oid
WHERE d.classoid = 'pg_extension'::regclass
  AND e.extname = 'myfdw';
```